# Is it possible to touch an "invisible" element on calabash-android?

Tags: android, ruby, automation, calabash, calabash-android

I am not able to touch an element on my app. I am able to query the element only when doing the command

```
query("all * text:'myText'")
```

which returns as result that the element is invisible (on screen is perfectly visible).

```
"class" => "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView",
                   "tag" => nil,
           "description" => "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{28d7250d V.ED.... ........ 0,0-145,49 #7f100141 app:id/textLabel}",
                    "id" => "textLabel",
                  "text" => "myText",
               "visible" => false,
                  "rect" => {
          "height" => 49,
           "width" => 145,
               "y" => 0,
               "x" => 0,
        "center_x" => 72,
        "center_y" => 24
    },
               "enabled" => true,
    "contentDescription" => nil
```

If I try to do:

```
touch(query("all * text:'myText'"))
```

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Action 'touch_coordinate' unsuccessful: Click can not be
>   completed!

I also tried this workaround:

```
b= query("all * text:'myText'")

touch(nil,
:offset=>{:x=>b[0]['rect']['center_x'],:y=>b[0]['rect']['center_y']})
```

> RuntimeError: Failed to perform gesture. java.lang.SecurityException:
>   Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission

Is there any way to touch this element?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your UI?

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen this was a case where the element you could see was marked as invisible but could be seen, but was covered by another element that was not visible but was not marked as invisible (I'm not sure how this was achieved!).  Interacting with this covering element provided the solution.  I used

```
flash("*")
```

in the console to cycle through all of the elements and counted out which ones were potential candidates, then tried interacting with them in turn.

Can't say if this will be the same for you but give it a try.

With regard to your error - Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission, this could indicate that the coordinates aren't behaving the way you expected, meaning you missed your app.  You could get the coordinates and try to use adb to send the touch event instead

```
adb shell input tap x y
```

Trying it in the console would probably be the easiest way to play around with this.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried tapping the button with ID rather than TEXT? I have button that needs to be pressed for long and gave this:

```
long_press_when_element_exists("* id:'#hiddenButtonID'")
```

and worked perfectly everytime.